# Embedding username and password in Excel Microsoft Data Query so other users can refresh data

Tags: sql-server, excel, passwords, connection

My company is using Tableau for Served data, but I have user who want Excel text table type data served - Text Tables with many columns, >100k Rows, color conditional formatting - which Tableau deals horribly with.

Everyone also has Excel, so I thought that I could set up an Excel file to pull the data from the SQL Server and be refreshed on demand by the users.  I had found an article here about using Microsoft Query within Excel to access the data source.

In Sql Server, I have a scheduled stored procedure that performs a nightly refresh of a results Table I have created I'll call that Table "[Server].[dbo].[Results]".  This is the Table that I was trying to display in Tableau - and everyone would have been able to access it, but it runs so slow, it is worthless.

I created the same thing in Excel, and it loads or refreshes data from [Server].[dbo].[Results] in < 30 secs with ~30 columns and > 100k rows with lots of colored conditional formatting.  It works great.

So, for Excel, I had our IT department create a user account that only has read-only access to the [Results] Table - that account does NOT have access to anything else in the Server Databases.  The credentials are something like Username = "ResultsUser" and Password = "ResultsPassword".  Again - EVERYONE would have had read-only access to this data if I could have gotten Tableau to work, so we don't care who knows this UserName and Password.  In my Excel file, I used these credentials when I created the Data Connection to [Server].[dbo].[Results], and I DID select "Save Password" for the Connection String

It refreshes fine for me on my work computer over our VPN, but when I sent the file to my user, she cannot refresh the data on her work computer over the VPN.  If I dig into the Connection Properties, even though I can see embedded "ResultsUser" and "ResultsPassword" in the Connection String, I also can see MY Windows UserID listed for the WSID.  Not sure if this is what is preventing my user from being able to refresh.

Some places I read, it sounds like the embedded credentials, just make it so the creator of the file (me) doesn't have to enter username and password when they refresh the data.  What I need is - with ResultsUser and ResultsPassword credentials embedded in the file - ANY USER of the Excel file can refresh the data - as long as they are on the network.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Is there something I am missing?  Do I need to use some other technique?

Thanks in advance,

MikeC

Comment: Why not use trusted authentication instad?

Comment: UserID doesn't matter, but yeah Excel sometimes forgets the username and password, you may need to actually type it into the connection string. Windows authentication might be easier (no username and password needed, just computer has to be AD joined), but you would need to ask your DBA to set that up